# Bulk edit or script multiple DXF files

Tags: cad, autocad

I have several hundred .dxf files that are all pretty simple rectangles with MText inside. I am looking for a way to, in bulk, convert the MText to Polylines (TXTEXP) without having to open each file individually. Is this possible? What are the scripting capabilities of AutoCad? I am open to any technique or software.

Comment: If they're text files then post an example of the contents here. Use the `{}` code formatting button.